# jquery real-time update for resizeable()

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to update some text in real-time when resizing a div. Right now this works in updating the text after you are finished resizing the #img1 div, but I would prefer if the pixel height and width could be shown and updated ***as*** you are dragging the jquery resizable handle.

```
    $( "#img1" ).resizable({
        grid: [10,10],
      });

    $('#img1').mouseup(function() {
      img1width = $("#img1").width();
      img1height = $("#img1").height();

      $( "#img1-height" ).html("H: "+img1height+"px");
      $( "#img1-width" ).html("W: "+img1width+"px");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.resizable provided resize: callback

```
$( "#img1" ).resizable({
    grid: [10,10],
    resize: function(event, ui){
      var img = event.target;
      //do your stuff
    }
});
```